# Centering text based on a larger width than the texts max-width

Tags: html, css

I have a p element inside two circles with borders and need to center the p element based on the width of the circles however I want to cause the p element to break into two lines without needing to create two p elements so I used a max-width. I believe that this is causing it not to center, but I could be wrong. If anyone knows a good hack to get around this please enlighten me

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v567c7q3/1/)

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">

    <p class="survive">Surviving Earth</p>

  </div>
</div>


.one {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px inset #81ff14;
}

.two {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px outset #81ff14;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.survive {
  font-size: 36px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 100px wide `<p>` is block-level, so it will not follow the inline `text-align: center` rule.  You need to give it an automatic left-right margin to put it in the horizontal center:

```
.survive {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Once you do this, you'll notice it sits a bit too far to the right.  That's because your first word is wider than the 100px limit (I measure about 140px) and the browser will not wrap inside a word.

```css
.one {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px inset #81ff14;
}

.two {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px outset #81ff14;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.survive {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">

    <p class="survive">Surviving Earth</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay thank you. I gave it a margin auto before and as you said it was too far to the right, I didn't know why thanks.

Comment: If you want to force a break, just insert a `<br />` tag between the words (if the text will always be the same).

Comment: funny question but is there a simple way to add a 3d measurement to an element. I'm looking for an effect like this but with code http://www.pimped-pixels.net/forum/uploads/profile/photo-3.gif?_r=1444683080